# Mapbox select road feature, how to return uncomposited features?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to build an interface in which the user can click to select a road. You can see a simple version here: https://codepen.io/lizzie-malk/pen/eYBWbjm

What I have noticed is that the features selected in the Mapbox Streets style, are often composite and not individual roads, particularly when selecting a smaller road, see photo below:

I'm assuming this is Mapbox simplifying the OSM information into their tileset. Is there any way around this using a Mapbox tileset, or is there a way to use the uncomposited OSM features in my own style?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I already found the best option – to use Overpass Turbo to add my own layer in a custom style, then the features are unchanged from OSM.
https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/overpass-turbo/